# require_once app mage php not found in external file

Tags: magento-1.9, cron

I am using following code in external file.

```
<?php 
require_once('../app/Mage.php');
//require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/app/Mage.php');

umask(0);
Mage::app();
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
echo $message = Mage::getVersion();
?>
```

When i am running my custom file from url its working.

Like `www.test.com/import/script.php`

But the same code not working with cron job.

There is error like PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Mage' not found

Comment: where is your script.php file is located ?? you can reference magento root directory in pub/ directory helath_check.php | get.php files

Comment: i have created one new folder import in root of magento. Ans script.php is inside import folder

Comment: then you can use `require_once dirname(__DIR__) . '../app/Mage.php'`

Comment: Already tried that. That is also not working. :(

Comment: try updated one

Comment: have you tried updated code? it is working now ??

Comment: This is also not working...

Comment: Try to echo `dirname(__DIR__)` name in your script.php so you can get proper path. now you add '../' if it is outside from your current directory add mutliple times if you need it.